# Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Tags: php, arrays

```
   <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'property-vas') > 0 || 
(isset($filenm) && $filenm != '')){
            if (array_search($d['postid'], array_column($sponsoredproparr, 
   'id')) !== false)
            {?>
        <?php } 
            else
            {?>
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $d['postid']; ?>" 
name="prop_id[]" value="<?php echo $d['postid']; ?>" 
     onclick="chk_single(this.checked,'<?php echo $d['postid']; ? 
     >');"/>&nbsp;

            <?php }
```

Above my code i have face Waring error:

> Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Comment: it says, `$sponsoredproparr` is null, check the code from did you get that variable

Comment: yes i get variable

Comment: So what is the content of `$sponsoredproparr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend, make sure that `$sponsoredproparr` is a **multi-dimensional array** or **an array of objects**, and its children have `id` property, see [php-manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). For example:

```
array(
  array(
    'id' => 2135,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 3245,
    'first_name' => 'Sally',
    'last_name' => 'Smith',
  )
);
```

to make sure; use this line:

```
<?php
    var_dump($sponsoredproparr);
?>
```